# How to get the java byte code class path in Gradle for android library?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to create the android library using "com.android.library"  plugin. I want to get the path of compiled java class path in Gradle script. Class files generated at build/intermediates/class path if I using com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 and same classes generated at build/intermediates/javac if I using com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0, why there is difference at path?

Comment: If you want to get all the class files, the best solution is to build a .jar/.aar file. inside that file, your compiled code will be there. To achieve this, goto Gradle -> assemble -> it will generate Jar or Aar file for you in build/intermediates/aar path. if you decompile or open this jar file you will get all the classes.   By that you can get specific library class files

Comment: What is your goal here? Can you provide more context?